# rpmbuild on CentOS 6.3 64-bit - broken dependencies

Tags: yum, centos6, 64-bit, dependencies, rpm

I'm trying to build a package using rpmbuild on 64-bit CentOS 6.3 server.

Here is the `spec` file:

```
Name:           test-fms
Version:        1.0
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        my FMS Package
Group:          Applications/Internet
License:        Nobody.
URL:            http://www.bla.com


Provides: test-fms = %{version}-%{release}

%description
test FMS server.

%prep

%build

%install
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
cp -r /workspace/%{name}/* $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/

%post

%clean
\rm -rf %{buildroot}

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
/opt/adobe/fms
```

When trying to install the package on another 64-bit CentOS 6.3 server, i get the following errors:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: test-fms-1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (myrepo)
           Requires: /usr/local/bin/perl
Error: Package: test-fms-1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (myrepo)
           Requires: librt.so.1
Error: Package: test-fms-1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (myrepo)
           Requires: libc.so.6
Error: Package: test-fms-1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (myrepo)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0)
Error: Package: test-fms-1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (myrepo)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)
Error: Package: test-fms-1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (myrepo)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)
Error: Package: test-fms-1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (myrepo)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.1)
Error: Package: test-fms-1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (myrepo)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.0)
Error: Package: test-fms-1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (myrepo)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.0)
Error: Package: test-fms-1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (myrepo)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1
Error: Package: test-fms-1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (myrepo)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1)
Error: Package: test-fms-1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (myrepo)
           Requires: libcurl.so.3
Error: Package: test-fms-1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (myrepo)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6
Error: Package: test-fms-1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (myrepo)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)
Error: Package: test-fms-1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (myrepo)
           Requires: libdl.so.2
Error: Package: test-fms-1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (myrepo)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)
Error: Package: test-fms-1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (myrepo)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0
Error: Package: test-fms-1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (myrepo)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3)
Error: Package: test-fms-1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (myrepo)
           Requires: libm.so.6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Although the RPM was built on 64-bit, it requires 32-bit packages, for example, for the `glibc` package, i have the 64-bit package installed, but the RPM dependencies requires `libc.so.6`:

```
[root@test ~]# yum provides libc.so.6
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.spd.co.il
 * extras: centos.spd.co.il
 * updates: centos.spd.co.il
updates/primary_db     | 4.6 MB     00:04     
glibc-2.12-1.80.el6.i686 : The GNU libc libraries
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Other       : libc.so.6
```

After playing with the spec file for a while I noticed that if I delete the `%files` part from the spec file, than no requirements are needed.

How can I fix this? what am I doing wrong?

Why does the RPM automatically adds the requirements? can I control it somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Problem:

After reading Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams answer I realized that rpmbuild is generating an automatic requirements list. Than, after a goole or two, i found the [Automatic Dependencies](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html) page, that says:

> When a package is built by RPM, if any file in the package's %files list is a shared library, the library's soname is automatically added to the list of capabilities the package provides. The soname is the name used to determine compatibility between different versions of a library.
>
> ...
>
> RPM does this by running ldd on every executable program in a package's %files list. Since ldd provides a list of the shared libraries each program requires, both halves of the equation are complete — that is, the packages that make shared libraries available, and the packages that require those shared libraries, are tracked by RPM. RPM can then take that information into account when packages are installed, upgraded, or erased.

### The Solution:

On the bottom of the page it says:

> There may be times when RPM's automatic dependency processing is not desired. In these cases, the autoreqprov tag may be used to disable it. This tag takes a yes/no or 0/1 value. For example, to disable automatic dependency processing, the following line may be used:
>
> **AutoReqProv: no**

So I've added the `AutoReqProv: no`  to my spec file (after the `Provides`) part, and all the bad dependencies were gone!

### Warning:

As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams wrote, normally this is a bad solution. Normally, you would like to get rid of all the 32-bit binaries and leave only the 64-bit ones. My solution works fro me since I am building a RPM based on someone's else code, and I don't want to start sorting his files. On the other hand, I do know what dependencies my rpm needs, and i can write them down myself. If this is the case for you - use the `AutoReqProv: no` flag. Otherwise - take Ignacio very good advice and get rig of the 32-bit code.

Answer (score 2):

You're putting 32-bit binaries in a 64-bit package. Don't do this. Build with a `--target` of `i386` instead.

Comment: The generated file is `test-fms-1.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm`, doesn't that mean it's 46-bit arch'? why should i use target of `i386`? i need a 64-bit one, so should i use `x86_64` instead? Thank

Comment: Building a 64-bit package doesn't magically turn the files it contains into 64-bit binaries.

Comment: Yea, i know that, as i said, the files **are already** 64-binaries as far as a know, i've built and used them on a duplicate 64-bit server. anyway, i've tried to use `--target=i386` and `--target=x86_64` and both didn't work, i386 failed because i'm installing on 64-bit, and x86_64 failed with the dependencies error. why does the RPM automatically adds the requirements? can i control it somehow?

Comment: You can, but you have no reason to do so. Remove the 32-bit binaries.

Comment: must be another option. the app i'm building maybe includes some 32-bit files, as well as 64-bit, but it uses only the 64-bit ones. I don't want to check all files and delete all the 32 ones, just ask the rpmbuild to ignore it. the full spec file has another recruitment that will make sure that all needed requirment will be there.

Comment: thanks for your help, eventually i found a way to achieve what I was after using the spec file. +1